# How to control developer property input to components via ESLint?

Tags: angular, npm, eslint

I'm building a design system, which can be imported into anyone's Angular library.

I wish to be able to, assuming they have this custom ESLint Plugin installed, throw error or warning messages when a developer is using the design system (made up of pre-built Angular components) and passes in (or doesn't pass anything in) invalid data into the component.

For example, lets say I create a button component.

This button component has an Input for the style - I.E Primary, Secondary, Tertiary. Each style modifies the look and feel of the button.

If however, someone was to pass in 'MadeUpStyle' into it - how would I create an ESLint Plugin to specifically throw up an error or a warning to advise them that what they're doing is not recommended?

Furthermore, if they do not pass anything into this Input, that an error would be presented stating that this is a required Input.

Whilst my research has helped me discover pages such as [this](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins), I can't seem to find anything online that specifically shows examples of someone using a plugin to validate component inputs.

Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What you describe is called `type-safety` and is handled by TypeScript by default. Specify types for your possible inputs in the component and everybody using it will get errors if used wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.

How would one define custom rules to control this

Comment: I really don't see why you would want to use eslint (hint, it gives *linting* advices). To achieve what I wrote all you have to do is create an angular library with your desired components. These components should specify their inputs explicitly (`@Input foo: 'primary' | 'secondary' | '..';`) rather than implicit or too vague (`@Input foo: any;` or `@Input foo: string;`).

Comment: I get what you mean - We already control the inputs explicitly via your example above, or via Interfaces/Enums, but what if someone was to specify a title of a component, but if we wanted to add a warning if they add a string that is less than 3 characters for example, but not necessarily an error?

Comment: Phew, gotcha. I don't see a way how that would be possible, sorry. Maybe somebody else has a good idea :) // Edit: Apparently @Ritesh mentioned `@Decorators` - This should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is You are looking to achieve two things:

- Type Safety for input properties of the components
- Required input properties

For, type safe input property, you can leverage Typescript itself, In tsConfig file you need to enable `strict` type checking for templates.
Refer this for more details on it: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

For required inputs you can create a custom decorators like this:

```
function Required(target: object, propertyKey: string) {
  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
    get() {
      throw new Error(`Attribute ${propertyKey} is required`);
    },
    set(value) {
      Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        value,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
      });
    },
  });
}
```

and then in your component:

```
    Component({
      selector: 'test-app',
      template: '<div></div>',
    });
    export class TestComponent {
      @Input() @Required a: number; // Usage of required
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks!

This seems to be working a treat, however when a value is specified, I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot redefine property: a" error. If I remove the setter, I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property a of [object Object] which has only a getter". Any Thoughts?

Comment: Can you produce a stackblitz? This is how I a using it and see no issues -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5ag6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I've just tried exactly that - despite having identical versions of all dependencies, and identical code in every way, I get an error in my local env, but not in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekhqhj?file=src/app/test-comp/required.ts

Comment: check your tsConfig.json file.

Comment: They are identical

Comment: Managed to resolve via adding another `configurable: true` to the parent `Object.defineProperty`